# Can someone fix the Cache problem in CodeIgniter or how to set cache in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I added this in my index funtion

```
 $this->output->set_cache_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
```

But an error was occured.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function CI_Output::set_cache_header(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\lsc\application\controllers\Home.php on line 24 and exactly 2 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsc\system\core\Output.php

Line Number: 792

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsc\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 24
Function: set_cache_header

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lsc\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Can someone tell me how to use this?

I want to set the cache for my website and tell me how to use the cache in website

Comment: Which version of CI are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent caching, use the `set_header` function instead:

```
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate', TRUE);
```

If you want to enable caching, pass two timestamp values to the function `set_cache_header` :

```
$this->output->set_header(time(), strtotime('+1 days'));
```

```
    /**
     * Set Cache Header
     *
     * Set the HTTP headers to match the server-side file cache settings
     * in order to reduce bandwidth.
     *
     * @param   int $last_modified  Timestamp of when the page was last modified
     * @param   int $expiration Timestamp of when should the requested page expire from cache
     * @return  void
     */
    public function set_cache_header($last_modified, $expiration)
```